# creating custom field type to upload video files and store it in asset library

Tags: column, custom, video

I have a requirement below.

my custom page layout should have a column which should accept video files and on saving the page, it should save the video to the asset library.

if the user uploads the video only it should be shown in the display page else it should be hidden.

so i decided to create a custom field type to satisfy all these requirements.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to create custom user field.

If you upload the videos by your own page you can use multiline text field with rich formatting in the list to "render" it do the display form. You upload the video in your page to assert library and then fill the field with the Object tag with proper SRC attribute referring to uploaded video.

Customize New and Edit form to exclude used field.

Comment: I am creating a custom page layout and everyday many pages will be created based on that page layout.and certain format is there to display video in pages as there is so many contents like images, text , dropdown managed metadata are in page layouts. And all the fields should be attached to the pagelayout through the custom content type.